# IDAPRO signature can't recognize open source library function

Tags: static-libraries, reverse, malware

Im trying to analysis a malware,Its include libevent library.
I have compiled libevent static library and create .sig file for IDAPRO.
But when i applying the .sig file in IDAPRO,its recognize 0 function in the malware
but the .sig file works when i open libevent dll file in IDAPRO.

how can i reconize this library function in IDAPRO